# Is it possible to export data from MS Azure SQL directly Into the Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-storage

Is there any direct way within the Azure MSSQL ecosystem to export SQL returned data set into the Azure table storage?

Something like BCP but with the Table Storage connection string on the -Output end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a service named `Azure Data Factory` which can directly copy data from Azure SQL Database to Azure Table Storage, even between other supported data stores, please see the section [`Supported data stores`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-data-movement-activities/#supported-data-stores) of the article "Data movement and the Copy Activity: migrating data to the cloud and between cloud stores" to know, but it is for Web, not like BCP command tool.

You can refer to the tutorial [`Build your first Azure data factory using Azure Portal/Data Factory Editor`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-build-your-first-pipeline-using-editor/) to know how to use it.

And as references, you can refer to the articles [Move data to and from Azure SQL Database using Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-sql-connector/) & [Move data to and from Azure Table using Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-table-connector/) to know how it works.